# How to reduce the heat from peppers in my tomato soup?

Tags: soup

I just made tomato soup with two cans of tomatoes with jalapeno peppers in it.  The soup has turned out to be too spicy.  How can I reduce the spicy (heat) level of the soup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a "safe" way to cook ghost chili?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/is-there-a-safe-way-to-cook-ghost-chili), http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-can-you-make-a-sauce-less-spicy-hot, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-can-you-reduce-the-heat-of-a-chili-pepper

Comment: @rumtscho : *maybe* the second one, but not the other two, which are related, but aren't an 'after it's already too spicy' type situation, and include stuff you can do to mitigate the problem in advance.

Comment: @Joe sure, I didn't expand the automatic comment. Of course the one about the sauce is the relevant one, the others complement the whole topic.

Answer (score 11):

Can make it a creamy tomato soup by adding heavy cream or half and half. While this will make the soup taste less spicy be careful if you get heartburn or other issues from eating spicy food, because it will not nullify those effects.

Comment: Capsaicin, the chemical in chillis that causes them to be hot, is an oil. Therefore the best way to neutralise it is with another oily or fatty substance: cream is perfect. +1

Answer (score 4):

Increase quantity of non-spicy stuff. In your case, add some tomatoes sans chilis, or other ingredients, depending on your recipe. (e.g. if there's cream in your soup, adding more of that will definitely cool it down some)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take out how much you need for 1 serving, reheat it with extra tomato sauce spiced, etc and kind of use your original soup as concentrate

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding cream as mentioned above, you can also add other fats like [butter](http://userealbutter.com/2009/12/04/tomato-soup-recipe/) (take it from the lobby if you want).

The threaded duplicate adds a considrable amount of knowledge on nullifying peppers generally, in the case of tomato soup particularly, fats to consider include also adding more broth with a roux, or perhaps a roasted vegetable puree of some sort covered in olive oil.

Answer (score 0):

You can also counter the heat with a little bit of sugar, I like to use honey

Comment: Sugar/honey does not "counter" the heat from capsicum. It just adds sweetness.

Comment: If it doesn't dilute the flavor of capsicum, then how can simple syrup be the grounds for testing Scoville units?

http://www.eatmorechiles.com/Scoville_Heat.html

Also on food and cooking refers to sugars as a method for helping cool the mouth after eating spicy foods?

Comment: The key word there is "dilute". You could dilute it in water, too; sugar just gives tasters something else to focus on. Sugar tends to dull *all* other tastes (not just spicy, also bitter, sour, etc.) but that is psychological rather than chemical. Adding sugar does not actually do anything at all to the amount or potency of capsaicin; by contrast, fat or alcohol *will* actually neutralize the flavour of the capsaicin itself.