# How do I reduce the heat in my white bean chicken chile

Tags: chili-peppers

How do I tone down the heat in a white bean chicken chile with corn that is made from the Omaha Steak side meal kit?

Comment: Does the recipe call for cream?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the heat from peppers in my tomato soup?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18461/how-to-reduce-the-heat-from-peppers-in-my-tomato-soup)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make a sauce less spicy/hot?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-can-you-make-a-sauce-less-spicy-hot)

Answer (score 2):

Dairy products have the impeccable ability to dampen heat from peppers, hot sauce and other spicy items. This includes milk (often drunk along with very spicy foods and peppers), sour cream, and cheese, among others.

I find Sour Cream not only adds to the complexity of flavors in most chili's (a great thing!), but also quells the heat quite a bit.

I'd leave your chili how it is, and then as you serve it, allow the individual to add sour cream to taste.

You can also top your chili with a healthy dose of your favorite cheese. This will help tame the heat a bit too. For white chili, jack or pepper jack cheese would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Add a can of beans and a can of corn?