# slow cooking with tabasco peppers

Tags: chicken, slow-cooking, spicy-hot

I'm cooking 4.5 lb of chicken in a slow cooker. I've yielded some tabasco peppers from the garden, poked holes in them with a fork, and add them to the liquid. Will this blow me out of the water? Will I notice the heat?

Comment: There are a lot of variables here .... (1) if the peppers cross-polinated with a hot or sweet variety, (2) how many you put in, (3) your personal preference for heat.

Comment: they are hot peppers. I only put in 3, sorry, I left that out for some reason, on a scale of 1-5, I probably prefer a 2-3. I've not been able to deal with eating bits of the tabasco pepper on it's own, at least not when they are big n juicy.

Comment: Assuming that the peppers are actually hot, and didn't cross polinate, most people would probably be fine ... but it sounds like you don't tolerate heat too well, so I really have no clue.  It might be a good idea to fish them out ... you can always add heat later.  If it's too hot when it's done, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18461/67

Comment: Can you expand on cross pollination ?

Comment: If you grow bell peppers and hot peppers too close to each other, you can end up with bell peppers that have some heat to them, and milder hot peppers ... but it's a crap shoot ... you don't know exactly what you're going to end up with

Comment: Dustin, can you revise your question?  As-is, it's unanswerable because of all of the variables, including: number of peppers, how hot they are, your pepper tolerance, length of cooking, volume of water, and what dish you're making with the chicken.