# How do I clean up my utensils after cutting extremely hot chillis?

Tags: cleaning, utensils, chili-peppers

As a corollary to a previous question:

[How to decide how much to dilute extremely hot chillis](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55926/how-to-dilute-the-concentration-of-extrememly-hot-chillis)

Are there any precautions or cleaning methods that I have to take when cutting said naga chillis? I've had chilli linger on surfaces before but they were never this hot.