# What happens to the heat/capsaicin content of a pepper when you roast it?

Tags: roasting, chili-peppers, chili

We received some extremely hot peppers of some sort in our CSA bin. They're a light green color and look like under-ripe habaneros, and we can't for the life of us figure out what kind of pepper they are. My dad used to tell me that eating spicy things would "put hair on my chest," but I think these peppers would burn the hair right off of my body, given the chance.

Since I'm not the biggest fan of deathly spicy peppers, we're considering roasting them to [reduce their heat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-can-you-reduce-the-heat-of-a-chili-pepper) to something similar to the peppers we normally use. I'm curious what happens to the capsaicin content of the pepper as a result of roasting it. Does anyone know how that works?

Comment: You can also use them diluted. E.g., use a few to spice up chili, or salsa. Also, if you roast them, I'd expect some of the capsaicin to become airborne, which you definitely don't want to inhale. Watch out for that (e.g., when opening the oven).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe roasting will reduce the 'heat' of the peppers, only make them tastier and more easily digested.

Only removing the seeds and the white membrane inside will reduce the heat, as far as I know.